# Post query - show posts from specified day and month and whole years

Tags: plugins, posts, query

I'm looking for widget or php query which I will be able to use as something like "on this day in history".

This query I want to show:
Posts published in the past on the same day and month, from whole years of publication.

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WP_Date_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_date_query/__construct/) in conjunction with [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/) to accomplish this.

```
$query = new \WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'date_query'     => array(
        array(
            'day'    => date( 'j', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ),
            'month'  => date( 'n', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ),
            'before' => 'this year'
        )
    )
) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        // Do stuff.

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to display posts related to specific date

```
$query_string = "order=ASC&posts_per_page=5";
function filter_where_date($where = '') {
$where .= " AND post_date = '2016-28-06'";
return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where_date' );
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
$custom_query->the_post(); 

} // end while
```